# Jquery Add a String at the end of the url in different cases

Tags: jquery, string, url

I need to add the string `$order=ASC` or `$order=DES`C at the end of the current url.

My problem is that i get this:

```
www.url.com/?order=ASC
```

And I need this

```
www.url.com/search.php?order=ASC
```

But also (using the same search.php script) i need to use url like this

```
www.url.com/search.php?status=active&name=bill&order=ASC
```

THis means, i have a link to `www.url.com/search.php?status=active&name=bill` and i need to add the order string at the end.

I looked here at stackoverflow but nothing works with the first example:

```
www.url.com/search.php?order=ASC
```

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't make any sense. What is the PHP script you are referring to? Can you post the existing code?

Comment: what are you doing with the URL once you add text to it ?

Comment: Is this a server-side question that you need solved with PHP?  Or is this a client-side question that you need solved with javascript?  And, are you only trying to add "order=ASC" onto the end of an URL?  Or are you also trying to add "search.php" onto the URL?

Comment: After you mentioned PHP i realized that I could solve my problem with it.. I did it.. The script is working, but it adds repettion of variables... For Example: 

I am on this www.myweb.com/search.php?order=asc

Then i clic order desc and i get this

www.myweb.com/search.php?order=asc&order=desc

It works, it shows me the list ordered in desc, but with this 2 variables on the url...

Answer (score 0):

With the [**myURL Plugin for jQuery**](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/03/jquery-myurl-extension-how-to-get-that.html) you could easily do that using the following:

```
var url = $.myURL("search.php", { order: 'ASC' });
```

With more data:

```
var url = $.myURL("search.php", { status: 'active', name: 'bill', order: 'ASC' });
// will render
// http://www.yoursite.com/search.php?status=active&name=bill&order=ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get this at all, but to get a querystring in JS, all you have to do is:

```
var qs = window.location.search;
```

To set a new querystring, do:

```
window.location.search = 'order=ASC';
```

Just be careful not to create an endless redirect loop.

> THis means, i have a link to
>   www.url.com/search.php?status=active&name=bill and i need to add the
>   order string at the end.

If this link is something like :

```
<a href="www.url.com/search.php?status=active&name=bill"></a>
```

do:

```
var oldURL = $('a').attr('href');
var newURL = oldURL+'&order=ASC';

$('a').attr('href', newURL);
```

If for some reason you need to add to the current URL :

```
var URL = window.location:
window.location = URL+'search.php?status=active&name=bill&order=ASC
```

To remove an old querystring before adding a new one do:

```
var URL = window.location.replace(window.location.search, '');
```

If you are sure there is a querystring, you could also do:

```
var URL = window.location.split('?')[0];
```

To check it the last character in the URL is a slash, and remove it, do:

```
var url = window.location;
var lastChar = url[url.length-1];

if (lastChar == '/') {
    url = url.substring(0, url.length-1);
}
```

By now you surely get the point, and you can pretty much get and set any URL and querystring.

Comment: I am goin to try this later... I solved the problem with php.. Thanks a lot for this piece of code.!